# Virtualbox apache performance tuning, what is best for one user?

Tags: php, performance, apache, virtualbox

I have an ubuntu LAMP server in virtualbox that I built from iso.  I have set up a host-only secondary NIC so that I can ssh into it and connect directly with my browser.  I then imported a rather heavy Drupal site, changes managed and exported through git.  My question is this, how do I configure Apache for the best performance in the situation where I know I will be the only one making requests?  I have improved response some by lowering the MaxClient and the MinimumSpare, but I would like to see it respond even faster.

I currently have 2 cores and 4G RAM allocated for the box, and I can take up to 4 cores and 12G from my host for this purpose without feeling much impact. 
With that in mind, I have been watching top while running page loads, and I rarely see apache2 use more than one core, so more muscle might not be the issue.  I was hitting some memory allocation limits, but then I increased PHP's usage rights to 1G and those were resolved.  It is an image heavy, dynamic site.

```
$ sed '/^#/ d' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5


<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers          5
MinSpareServers       1 
MaxSpareServers      10
MaxClients           30
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers          2
MinSpareThreads       5
MaxSpareThreads      75 
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients           30
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
StartServers          2
MinSpareThreads       5
MaxSpareThreads      75 
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients           30
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy all
</Files>

DefaultType None

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

Include httpd.conf

Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

Include conf.d/

Include sites-enabled/
```

Comment: This is more a question for either [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Hmm, I can see that point.